# how to change action method name with action name attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my controller

```
     [ActionName("Articles")]
     public ActionResult ArticleSubmitted()
       { 
        var articles = db.Articles.ToList()
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.PostedDate)
        .Select(e => new ArticleViewModel()
        {
           ArticleId = e.ArticleId,
           Title = e.Title,
           PostedByName = e.ApplicationUser.UserName,
           PostedDate = e.PostedDate,
           PageContent = e.PageContent
        });
        return View(articles);
    }
```

I want to action method name but for its to working, 
I have to change the last line to:

```
  return View(ArticleSubmitted);
```

then it will display proper action name,but i that case i am unable to pass articles to view so how to change it to return articles too.

Comment: pass model as second parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this overloads of view, i think it should work:

```
return View("ArticleSubmitted", articles);
```

Moreover, if u are calling that particular action method from somewhere else then change action method name from ArticleSubmitted to Articles like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("name of text", "Articles", "Controller name")
```

Comment: it is woking fine thnks @duke

Answer (score 0):

Use `ViewData.Model` to pass your model to View like this:

```
 [ActionName("Articles")]
 public ActionResult ArticleSubmitted()
   { 
    var articles = db.Articles.ToList()
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.PostedDate)
    .Select(e => new ArticleViewModel()
    {
       ArticleId = e.ArticleId,
       Title = e.Title,
       PostedByName = e.ApplicationUser.UserName,
       PostedDate = e.PostedDate,
       PageContent = e.PageContent
    });
    ViewData.Model = articles;
    return View(ArticleSubmitted);
}
```

Comment: I know viewdata viewbag etc but is there any overload of view possible to send both of them together

Comment: @neo yes, you have 2 overloads `View(IView view, object model)` and `View(string viewName, object model)` you always can use them. I just think that filling `Model` property more obvious way to write controller.

Comment: then what is the syntax for that return view(ArticleSubmitted, what should be here ) model.articles or something new model(articles)

Comment: I suppose `View(ArticleSubmitted, articles);` like @Musthaan said you.

Comment: not working has some invalid arguments u can try too @ teo van kot

Comment: @neo can you say what `ArticleSubmitted` is in your case? Definition? Also, what version of MVC do you use?

Comment: ArticleSubmitted is the name of view and articles is the collection of property i want to render on view it is giving http 404 error and still searching for //localhost:44305/Articles/ArticleSubmitted even i have configured action name i am using mvc5